# Duplicate and manipulate xml elements via xslt in one step

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to copy some parts (between criteria) of an xml and manipulate some values in the copied parts in one step. This is what should be done:

1. Look for TextSymbol[SymbolKey>=2000 AND <=3000]
2. Copy matched node TextSymbol
3. Update value of SymbolKey in copied node with prefix 92

**Here is my source xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TextSymbols>
    <TextSymbol>
        <SymbolKey>1000</SymbolKey>
        <Name>PHY</Name>
    </TextSymbol>
    <TextSymbol>
        <SymbolKey>2000</SymbolKey>
        <Name>LEX</Name>
    </TextSymbol>
    <TextSymbol>
        <SymbolKey>3000</SymbolKey>
        <Name>TIR</Name>
    </TextSymbol>
</TextSymbols>
```

**Goal is:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TextSymbols>
    <TextSymbol>
        <SymbolKey>1000</SymbolKey>
        <Name>PHY</Name>
    </TextSymbol>
    <TextSymbol>
        <SymbolKey>2000</SymbolKey>
        <Name>LEX</Name>
    </TextSymbol>
    <TextSymbol>
        <SymbolKey>3000</SymbolKey>
        <Name>TIR</Name>
    </TextSymbol>
    <TextSymbol>
        <SymbolKey>922000</SymbolKey>
        <Name>LEX</Name>
    </TextSymbol>
    <TextSymbol>
        <SymbolKey>923000</SymbolKey>
        <Name>LEX</Name>
    </TextSymbol>
</TextSymbols>
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: Do you want fries with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud write the script the following way:

1. Template matching `TextSymbols` should:

   - Apply templates just like the *identity template*.
   - Then apply templates again, but only for `TextSymbol` with
     `SymbolKey` in the desired range in a "special" (`prepend`) mode.
2. There should be a template matching `SymbolKey` in `prepend` mode,
   which writes to the output "92" (the string to prepend) and then its
   own value.
3. And two more extensions to the *identity template*. It should:

   - Be executed in **all** modes (`mode="#all`).
   - The contained `apply-templates` should keep the current mode (`mode="#current"`)

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="TextSymbols">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="prepend"
        select="TextSymbol[number(SymbolKey) ge 2000 and number(SymbolKey) le 3000]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SymbolKey" mode="prepend">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select="concat('92', .)"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="#all">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/gVAjbSY

And a note concerning your expected result:

You didn't write anything about changing the content of `Name` elements,
so I assume that this element in the last output `TextSymbol` should be
`TIR` (like in the input), not `LEX`.